# Reference Color from Data Frame in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(GROUP = factor(c("AL", "AS", "B", "HI", "I", "P", "T", "W", "E", "NE", "EL", "EP", "SW", "SOD"), ordered = TRUE),
                 color.codes = c("#000000", 
                                 "#b05cc6",
                                 "#afb045",
                                 "#7777c8",
                                 "#db8f47",
                                 "#4dacd0",
                                 "#cb5242",
                                 "#56b88f",
                                 "#c75a88",
                                 "#5db74e",
                                 "#4f7e3b",
                                 "#ff0000",
                                 "#8d7134",
                                 "#000080"),
                 Year = rep(paste0(2010:2025, "-", 2011:2026), each=14),
                 value = runif(224))

df$Year <- factor(df$Year,
                  levels=sort(unique(df$Year)), 
                  ordered=TRUE)

ggplot(df, 
               aes(x = Year, y = value, color = GROUP, group = GROUP)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dotted") + # make all dotted by default
  geom_line(data = (df %>% filter(Year <= "2014-2015")),
            aes(x = Year, y = value, color = GROUP),
            lty = "solid") + # and then make all prior to 2015 solid
  scale_color_manual(values = df$color.codes) +
  xlab("School Year") + 
  ylab("Proficiency Rate")
```

[image]

Let's examine the data frame:

```
> head(df)
  GROUP color.codes      Year     value
1    AL     #000000 2010-2011 0.5540173
2    AS     #b05cc6 2010-2011 0.0301139
3     B     #afb045 2010-2011 0.7469069
4    HI     #7777c8 2010-2011 0.4981707
5     I     #db8f47 2010-2011 0.9677573
6     P     #4dacd0 2010-2011 0.7777855
```

For example, `#b05cc6`, according to Google, is something of a [purple shade](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23b05cc6&oq=%23b05cc6&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). But it clearly looks red, despite that it's supposed to be purple.

It also doesn't make any sense that `B` has the same color as `AL`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Try stringsAsFactors = FALSE in your dataframe, and maybe scale_colour_identity()

Comment: @baptiste How does one use `scale_color_identity()` here? When I use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, groups `AL` and `W` have the same color.

Comment: Iirc scale_manual wants a named vector. I'm guessing you want to use unique() for its values, otherwise you get repeats. But better let ggplot do the mapping and replace scale_manual with scale_identity. (from cellphone)

Comment: @baptiste The problem with having ggplot do the mapping is that I, along with another person, are trying to maintain the same color scheme. It doesn't make sense to type out all of these like how it is done in most examples.

Comment: @baptiste `unique()`, unfortunately, still leads to the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a palette of group names and colour code mappings:

```
pal = unique(df[,c("GROUP","color.codes")])

> head(pal)
  GROUP color.codes
1    AL     #000000
2    AS     #b05cc6
3     B     #afb045
4    HI     #7777c8
5     I     #db8f47
6     P     #4dacd0
```

Fixup color codes to be character and not factor, or else they get converted to numeric and looked up in the palette:

```
> pal$color.codes=as.character(pal$color.codes)
```

Now create a named vector from the palette columns:

```
> pval = pal$color.codes
> names(pval) = pal$GROUP
> pval
       AL        AS         B        HI         I         P         T         W 
"#000000" "#b05cc6" "#afb045" "#7777c8" "#db8f47" "#4dacd0" "#cb5242" "#56b88f" 
        E        NE        EL        EP        SW       SOD 
"#c75a88" "#5db74e" "#4f7e3b" "#ff0000" "#8d7134" "#000080"
```

Then use that in `scale_color_manual(values=pval)`.

Now AS looks purply, B looks like a sort of greeny vom colour.

[image]

EP looks red. etc.